# How to launch activity from service properly?

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I have a activity that can launch a service after the user presses the button. In this service, i have a Timer that runs every 10s. I want to run another activity (google maps) from this service every 10s. 
If i put it in service i get this error:

```
12-29 10:09:21.369: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(235): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

Where shoud i put my code to launch activity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error message said, You need set the flag in your `Intent`

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MyService.this,MyActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Why do I need to place it in a new task? Dont u want it to usually belong to the same task?